# Is there a way to tell (at build-time) if my 10.9 app will run on 10.8?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

I have an app I've been developing under 10.9 using the 10.9 SDK, and I want to distribute it to my friends who are running 10.8.  I know I can't guarantee it'll work there without finding an OS X 10.8 system (maybe in a virtual machine) and running it there, but is there any way I can check that I'm not using any 10.9-only APIs?  Or even get a list of 10.9-only APIs that my application uses?

My understanding is that:

- "Deployment Target" doesn't do this -- this just sets the LC_VERSION_MIN_MACOSX, so that if you tried to run it on an earlier version of OS X, it would refuse to even start.
- "Base SDK" doesn't do this -- this is the version of the API it's compiled with.  Some features added in newer versions of the SDK are available even on older versions of OS X at runtime (e.g., NSArray -firstObject).

Xcode's static analysis is pretty good at identifying the source of symbols (classes / methods) that I use, so it seems like this should be fairly easy to do, but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: I don't think that such a tool exists. I'd love to be proved wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Base SDK" does what you want in a *legalistic* sense. Yes you may get some false negatives - for methods like `firstObject` - but better those than false positives. You can check any reported non-existant APIs and put in code to check dynamically (`respondsToSelector:`) and code defensively for those cases, or ignore them if you must and are really sure they are available.

Comment: I would tend to agree, *except* that Xcode/Clang seem to give up after they reach a certain number of issues, and for an app which wasn't originally written with the older SDK in mind, there can be a lot of false negatives.  A clean build of my app will report a dozen or so "firstObject" problems, and then bail.

Comment: You can up the error limit with `-ferror-limit=0`, the default is 20, 0 means unlimited (see [Clang command line options](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#options-to-control-error-and-warning-messages)). For testing you could also `#if` a category on `NSArray` to define `firstObject` pre 10.9 to silence those particular warnings - include the category's `.h` in your project's `.pch`, etc. It's not perfect, but you can make do (and a slew of VMs helps!)